# How to utilize cross references in Microsoft Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003, cross-reference

I am compiling a document full of figures with captions and cross-referencing them in a paragraph before the figure.  My problem is if I add a new figure before another, the cross-reference gets mucked up.  The link actually takes me to the right figure, but the cross-reference text is wrong.  It doesn't get updated.  Is there a quick fix for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then press <kbd>F9</kbd>. This updates the text for all references.

Comment: Nice!! All this time I didn't know this..